# Вопрос по созданию сервера с помощью Eclipse и Jetty

Tags: java, сервер, jetty

Здравствуйте С недавних пор решил изучать Java. Нашел недавно новые туториалы и там в качестве домашки надо написать:

*-Обычный HelloWorld в Eclipse(с этим справился)*

*-Написать приложение,которое запускает jetty-server и можно зайти на него через браузер и увидеть страничку с helloworld.*

**Скачал:**
*jetty-all-9.3.7.v20160115-uber*

*servlet-api-2.5*
Смог добавить их в eclipse. далее нашел туториал по запуску сервера с helloworld с помощью jetty:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-embedding.html#downloading-jars

И тут я стопорнулся. Какой проект нужно создать в Eclipse? На хабре прочел, что dynamic web project, но в официальном туториале никакой информации. Если создаю динамический веб-проект,слева открывается целый список библиотек и прчоего. В него добавить jetty я смог, а что дальше-не знаю. Не понимаю, где писать код, приведенный в туторе и как вообще оно все стыкуется друг с другом(

Понимаю, что вопрос может глупый, но спрашивать мне больше не у кого, а хочется решить задачку и двигаться дальше). 
Заранее благодарен за внимание

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал сразу завести хорошую привычку и, по возможности, вообще никогда не пользоваться поддержкой проектов в IDE. Практически для любого языка программирования существует такое понятие как [система сборки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8). Для Java это [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) и [Gradle](http://gradle.org/).

Начните с Maven, он более популярен, и используется практически во всех туториалах. В дальнейшем, если вы захотите (а вы захотите) попробовать другую IDE, то без труда перенесете в нее свои проекты.

Для создание Maven проекта в Eclipse нажмите *Ctrl + 3* и напишите *new maven pro*. Учтите, что Maven требует определенной [организации кода проекта](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Пример приложения (как раз с использованием Maven) можно [посмотреть тут](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/maven-and-jetty.html).

---

[Вот проект](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-embedding.html), который, как я понимаю, вам нужно сделать. Пример из официальной документации Jetty. Что касается его сборки, то у вас есть выбор:

С использованием средств IDE:

- создать обычный Java проект в IDE;
- [скачать](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jetty.aggregate%7Cjetty-all%7C9.3.7.v20160115%7Cpom) и [подключить](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project's_classpath%3F) необходимые библиотеки (`jetty-all.jar`);
- [запустить](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm);

С использованием Maven:

- [создать Maven проект](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html);
- описать [необходиые библиотеки](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jetty.aggregate%7Cjetty-all%7C9.3.7.v20160115%7Cpom) и плагины в pom.xml;
- запустить через [maven-exec-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html);

Разница в том, что когда вы пользуетесь проектом в IDE, то скачиваете все библиотеки вручную, и все настройки проекта сохраняются в конфигурационном файле, **специфичном для данной IDE**.

Когда вы пользуетесь системой сборки, то описываете конфигурацию проекта в формате, специфичном для системы сборки (для Maven это XML). Библиотеки автоматически скачиваются из [центрального репозитория](http://search.maven.org/) при сборке проекта. Все настройки описываются в декларативном виде. При необходимости вы можете импортировать этот проект в **любую IDE**.

Второй вариант выглядит сложнее, первый раз всегда трудно, но вы от него совершенно точно никуда не денетесь. Смотрите сами, что вам сейчас удобнее.

Comment: Понимаете, я просматриваю лекции Технопарка. В свободном доступе есть только видео с лекций, где дается домашка, к сожалению  я нигде не нашел ее реализацию. Но хочу попытаться ее сделать самостоятельно. А там они по лекциям делают со студентами игру, в которую можно поиграть на сервере, который реализован с помощью jetty. 

Что jetty, что Maven для меня-темный лес. Я ранее не занимался такими вещами, поэтому такие вопросы.. Maven не слишком сложная система?
что значит поддержка проектов в IDE? 
с основами Java я вообще знакомился в Ideea, сейчас Eclipse выглядит не таким удобным)

Comment: @Iga Обновил ответ. Попробуйте для начала просто погуглить, почитать и разобраться что такое classpath, библиотеки, и как они подключаются в IDE. Maven не сложный. Он ускоряет и упрощает стандартные задачи в разы. Погуглите `maven hello world` на русском и попробуйте собрать.

Comment: @Iga Кстати, прошу прощения, за невнимательность. Там на странице внизу [есть ссылка](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/maven-and-jetty.html) на пример этого же проекта со сборкой через maven. Так что вам осталось только скопировать и разобраться. Удачи. :) Если есть еще вопросы предлагаю перейти в чат.

Comment: огромное спасибо за инструкцию, обязательно попробую. касаемо возможных вопросов, если вы не возражаете, можно ли как-то с вами связываться не здесь, а через соц.сети,мейл,или скайп?если конечно вас не затруднит отвечать на вопросы по java.

Comment: @Iga StackOverflow и придуман для того, чтобы сообщество могло подсказать нужное решение. Это хорошее место, чтобы задать вопрос. Кроме того, поможет тем, кто столкнется с аналогичной проблемой после вас. А так, конечно,. мэйл в профиле, пишите.